# SIMCOM A7672SA using AGPS

Tags: gps, esp32

I'm using the A7672SA module to get GPS information, but I'm wondering that does it suppoer the AGPS feactures on it. I found AT+CAGPS command from the AT command manual but I have no idea how to get the AGPS informations.

Once I set AT+CAGPS command it is showing +AGPS: success but then ?

> AT+CGPSINFO

> AT+CGNSSINFO

commands only works when it get the GPS signals not from the AGPS server. Also, I can't find any AGPS server setting command at all.

Cheers.
HS

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @BadIdeaException I need to get the AGPS command. I mean how to get the AGPS data from the module.